# Can't connect to wireless network with Linksys WUSB11 v.2.6 adapter, networks visible

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

I just set up a dual boot on an old HP computer and have upgraded to 12.04, but I am still having trouble getting connected wirelessly. Note: I have read many other posts with similar problems but none of their solutions have done the trick yet. I have gotten as far as being able to view wireless networks by virtue of installing atmel firmware, but no luck connecting still.

My router is WEP encrypted and a wireless-G router from Linksys, whereas my wireless USB adapter is wireless-B if that makes a difference. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here are some outputs to help anyone get started with me:

**When trying to connect to my network:**

```
iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11b  ESSID:"Biokids"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 00:21:29:6B:35:38   
      Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=42/100  Signal level=42/100  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

**Shortly thereafter:**

```
iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11b  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux    Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 058f:9360 Alcor Micro Corp. 8-in-1 Media Card Reader
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 077b:2219 Linksys WUSB11 V2.6 802.11b Adapter
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
```

Please request/instruct as necessary.

Comment: Is your router set to mixed mode 802.11b and g? Please see here: http://sim.dlink.ca/images/faqs/How_do_I_change_the_80211_Mode_on_my_DIR_series_router/step3.jpg

Comment: Yes, although the interface is slightly different. Wireless network mode is set to mixed, although there is no mention of 802.11b. Just like the images half way down the page here: http://www.justanswer.com/computer-networking/4e8hi-trying-hookup-new-linksys-wrt54g2-browser.html Also, fwiw everything works fine and I can connect when I boot using windows.

Comment: Are there any clues here? With the ethernet detached and as you are trying to connect: cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e wlan -e etwork | tail -n20. Please post here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Tried it out and got this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6378930/

Comment: I did it again and recorded it about every 10 seconds for a few rounds: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6378949/

Comment: Any other thoughts out there in the world of Ubuntu experts? I still am unable to connect. If I were to buy a wireless-G network adapter, would it likely work better with my current router (also wireless-G)? Thanks for all the help thus far.

Answer (score 0):

We see a lot of these entries in your logs:

```
ieee80211 phy0: wlan0: No probe response from AP xx:yy after 500ms, disconnecting.
```

You might set a longer wait time:

```
sudo -i
echo "options mac80211 probe_wait_ms=3000"  >> /etc/modprobe.d/mac80211.conf
exit
```

Sometimes, it also helps to set the correct reulatory domain; check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If yours is blank or incorrect for your country from here, then explicitly set it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Right above exit 0, add the correct code:

```
iw reg set US
```

Of course, set your code if not US. Proofread, save and close gedit. Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

Comment: I ran the instructed code, but still no luck. Here is the result of the previous test: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6384454/

Comment: The regulatory domain was successfully changed to US. Here are some results of a few other commands that may be useful:http://paste.ubuntu.com/6384504/